# Individual column Validation Based Off The Previous Date Columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, validation, validation-list-items, column-validation

**SharePoint Online Classic View**

Really need some help with this.

I have a custom list with 8 visible date columns
Column name examples: **Create Date, Start Date, O365 Queue and Date Closed**.

Create date and Start Date can be what ever the user wants but Date closed can't be before Create neither can O365 Queue or any other date columns(not counting the system or calculated columns)

I know to go to the validation settings at the top of list settings but I'm not sure how to get validations to work for multiple columns.

Additionally not all columns will be filled out the first time around. I need to be able to leave some of the date columns with out it throwing an exception or error.

Date Closed can equal any other column but it cant be less than them.

A columns date can't be before the one that came before it in the form.

I was thinking a workflow validation may be the way to go but I haven't cracked that shell open just yet.

Any help or tips would go very far and be very appreciated.

Comment: Javascript validation will be better on PreSaveAction function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **list validation**, which works in both classic and modern experience on SharePoint Online, then this is the formula you want:

`=AND(AND([Date Closed]>=[O365 Queue],[Date Closed]>=[Start Date]),[Date Closed]>=[Create Date])`

Make sure to provide users a clear message on why the validation fails, something like:

> The 'Date Closed' cannot be before the following dates: 'O365 Queue', 'Start Date' and 'Create Date'!

---

Other ways to make this work in classic experience is with custom CSR (client-side rendering) applied to the field. If you need this solution as well, let me know and I can provide it.

Comment: CSR version would be great too.